# Create buttons with data from divs

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

So i have these divs created from wordpress post and they have data attribute which is taken from php `<?php echo $rengdata->format('Y-m'); ?>`

```
<div class="renginiai-box">
     <div class="col-sm-3" data-renginiolaikas="2017-09"></div>
     <div class="col-sm-3" data-renginiolaikas="2017-09"></div>
     <div class="col-sm-3" data-renginiolaikas="2017-09"></div>
     <div class="col-sm-3" data-renginiolaikas="2017-10"></div>
</div>
```

What I need right now is to create one single button with unique date. Result should be like this.

```
<div class="laikotarpis">
      <button value="2017-09" class="laiko-btn">2017 09</button>
      <button value="2017-10" class="laiko-btn">2017 10</button>
</div>
```

I have no idea what function could fit this. Should I make array or there is a jQuery function for this

Comment: you need client side programming for this. What have you tried?

Comment: Your question contains no question.

Comment: You can achieve this with JS and/or jQuery

Comment: I know this work for jquery, but I have no idea from what to start

Comment: First of all, try to be more descriptive, show us more of the project, explain where you want this code to be, etc

Comment: It would make much more sense to do this in PHP. Group your result set by the date. Doing this in JS would lead to a FOUC and unnecessary HTML in the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jQuery to iterate through all elements with the data attribute `data-renginiolaikas` and append a button:

```
$('[data-renginiolaikas]').each(function(s, e) {
  var val = $(this).attr('data-renginiolaikas');
  if(!$('.laikotarpis button[value=' + val + ']').length) {
  $('.laikotarpis').append('<button value="' + val + '" class="laiko-btn">' + val.replace('-',' ') + '</button>');
  }
});
```

Example: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KZQgBw

Comment: This actaully works, but it creates buttons with same values

Comment: Ah I missed that, sorry - check out the updated answer, I added a check to see if the button already exists before adding it.

Answer (score 0):

I think that this is much closer :

```
$('[data-renginiolaikas]').each(function(s, e) {
   if($('.laikotarpis button').val() != $(this).attr('data-renginiolaikas')){
        $('.laikotarpis').append('<button value="' + $(this).attr('data-renginiolaikas') + '" class="laiko-btn">' + $(this).attr('data-renginiolaikas').replace('-',' ') + '</button>');
   }
});
```

Fork of [delinear](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48166486/5890686)'s answer

https://codepen.io/boian-ivanov/pen/MrQjPy